# Bulk user import to firebase with unhashed passwords

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm currently at middle of a project and I have two questions. Sorry I only mentioned one in the title. However this is the first question.

1. Is it possible to import bulk of users (Say .json file of Email and unhashed password of each user) to Firebase as Project Users (Under Authentication Section)?

**Problem Background**

Since this project needs a login system, I thought to use firebase authentication to verify users because free version also can have Unlimited registered users as [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits) guide says under Accounts per project . However in order to do my project, it is required to add users (More like 200 users) as registered users in Firebase Authentication.

**Problem**

So I installed Firebase CLI and setup the environment and converted CSV to JSON file and used following command to upload users and create accounts.

```
firebase auth:import users.json --hash-algo='SCRYPT' --hash-key='gcECkBfvL2ysRjYG6XBAJji1DayU8mqlABjstqJnw63Vx9jbd1xVDT3KgHcKAa5BFlk87cl/vAQ8mTDla4hxGg==' --salt-separator='Bc==' --rounds=8 --mem-cost=14
```

Here I got the second problem. Which is that after running the command, terminal did not show me any successful message but just finished processing.

[image]

I cannot understand why this finished without any message (Success or error). Also I want to mention that my JSON did not contained Hashed passwords. but just plain password.

So those are my two questions.

1. Is it possible to import bulk of users (Say .json file of Email and unhashed password of each user) to Firebase as Project Users(Authentication)? And make Firebase to hash passwords when it stores them?
2. Why this auth:import did not show any message? When I visit console to see users, there was not any. Which means upload was not successful.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You can't do bulk import of unhashed passwords, but you can hash them and then import them with the just hashed passwords.